# Making 475(f) election just for this year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-loss, h-1b-visa

I suffered losses in the stock market far exceeding the allowable loss deduction of $3000. I was working on an H1-B visa when I faced this loss. I was wondering whether I could elect to use 475(f) only for this year so that I could treat my capital loss as an ordinary loss and reduce my tax bill. I was trading pretty regularly; my broker-provided 8949 runs into several pages.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty summary is basically that you have to be able to make a compelling argument to the IRS that you're trading as a business on short-term swings of the market.

We can't give a definitive answer, and can't even really make an educated guess without a lot more information about how and how often you trade. Though the fact that you want to do it for one year only suggests not.

[Here's what the IRS has to say about it](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc429)

> Traders
>
> Special rules apply if you're a trader in securities, in the business
>   of buying and selling securities for your own account. The law
>   considers this to be a business, even though a trader doesn't maintain
>   an inventory and doesn't have customers. To be engaged in business as
>   a trader in securities, you must meet all of the following conditions:
>
> - You must seek to profit from daily market movements in the prices of securities and not from dividends, interest, or capital
>     appreciation;
> - Your activity must be substantial; and
> - You must carry on the activity with continuity and regularity.
>
> The following facts and circumstances should be considered in
>   determining if your activity is a securities trading business:
>
> - Typical holding periods for securities bought and sold;
> - The frequency and dollar amount of your trades during the year;
> - The extent to which you pursue the activity to produce income for a livelihood; and
> - The amount of time you devote to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kevin's answer, you must apply to the IRS to be approved for Trader Tax Status (MTM accounting)  and it's not easy to get approval.

Per https://greentradertax.com/trader-tax-center/trader-tax-status/how-to-qualify/ , their requirements for TTS are based  on trader tax court cases and their vast experience with IRS and state controversy for traders. To qualify, the trader must:

- Trades full time or part time for a good portion of the day, almost every day the markets are open.
- Holding period: Is the most important factor, and in the Endicott court, the IRS said average holding period must be 31 days or less.
- Makes 720 total trades per year (Poppe court) on an annualized basis. About four trades per day, four days per week, 16 trades per week, and 60 trades a month.
- Executes trades on close to four days per week, every week. Around 75% frequency.
- Has proceeds in the millions of dollars per year on equities.
- Spends more than four hours per day…
- Has few to no sporadic lapses in the trading business during the year.
- Has the intention to run a business and make a living.
- Has significant business equipment, education, business services, and a home office.
- Account size: Has a material account size.